# Unhandled internal error when executing lua script

Tags: lua

In getting an error "Unhandled internal error" when executing the below code.
I'm trying to convert hh:mm:ss to minutes.

I tried part of the code in https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo and it works. Not sure what's wrong in here.

```
function getMinutes(hours, minutes, secs)
    return ((hours * 60) + minutes + (secs / 60))
end

local lOrder = Order:Get()
local orderPlacedTime = lOrder.CreateDateTime

local ptoStartHour, ptoStartMin, ptoStartSec = startTime:match("(.+):(.+):(.+)")
local ptoEndHour, ptoEndMin, ptoEndSec = endTime:match("(.+):(.+):(.+)")

local ptoStartTime = getMinutes(ptoStartHour, ptoStartMin, ptoStartSec)
local ptoEndTime = getMinutes(ptoEndHour, ptoEndMin, ptoEndSec)

local orderTime = getMinutes(orderPlacedTime.Hour, orderPlacedTime.Min, orderPlacedTime.Sec)
```

if startTime="12:12:60"
i'm expecting ptoStartTime to have 733

Comment: "Unhandled internal error" is not a message from Lua.

Comment: Better use `(%d%d)` instead of `(.+)`. Put some debug prints into your script to find out where it crashes.